# I am getting a variable 'b' in json response as b0 ,b1 variables how to consume in my java pojo?

Tags: java, json, spring, pojo

I am getting a variable'b'in json response as b0,b1 variables how to consume in my java pojo?
This is my response-

```
{
"@a":"abc",
"b0":{
        "@name":"b0",
        "@nodes":[]},
"b1":{
        "name":"b1",
        "node":"s1"
     },
"@nodes":[
           "b0","b1"
         ]
}
```

This is my pojo that consumes the json or serializes it-

```
public class ABC {
    private String a;
    private List<b> b;
    private List<String> nodes;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("@a")
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public List<b> getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(List<b> b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<String> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    @JsonProperty("@nodes")
    public void setNodes(List<String> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }}
```

This is entity b-

```
public class b {   
    private String name;        
    private String node;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
   public void setName(Integer name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getNode() {
        return node;
    }
   public void setNode(Integer node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more. What is Input and What output your are expecting. And what type of code you have written. Share the code snippet also

Comment: Can't see a1, a2, a3 in the json?

Comment: That json format looks odd, have you edited it before including it in your post? I think you need to clarify your question and what kind of json format you have.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question-    I am getting a variable 'b' in json response as b0 b1 variables how to consume in my java pojo?

Comment: public class ABC {

 private String a;
        private List<b> b;                                                                      
                                                                                                      
       @JsonIgnore
 public String getNodeId() {
  return nodeId;
 }


 @JsonProperty("@a")
 public void setA(String a) {
  this.a = a;
 }                                                                                                            public List<b> getB() {
  return b;
 }

 public void setB(List<b> b) {
  this.b = b;
 }

Comment: this is my pojo consuming the json

Comment: You are not getting a variable 'b' in your json, you have two variables 'b0' and 'b1' instead. Please be precise in what your problem is and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, I would recommend using `@JsonAnySetter` annotation. In fact, you receive vars called b0, b1 (and maybe more of them : b2, b3, you didn't clarify this) and want to put them in a `List` which is not a default behavior of jackson at all. You can do this as following : (My code may contain some few mistakes because it's always easier to write code within an IDE but you should get the idea here).

```
public class ABC {
private String a;
private List<b> b = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> nodes;

@JsonAnySetter
public void setBxValues(String bname, String bvalue) throws IOException {
   // instanciating one object mapper each time is quite CPU consuming
   // so beware of this if you care about CPU performance of your app
   ObjectMapper obMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   // turning the stringified b json object into a B POJO instance.
   B bObject = obMapper.readValue(bvalue, B.class);
   // adding it to the list of bs
   b.add(bObject);
}

@JsonIgnore
public String getNodeId() {
    return nodeId;
}

@JsonProperty("@a")
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public List<b> getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(List<b> b) {
    this.b = b;
}

@JsonIgnore
public List<String> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

@JsonProperty("@nodes")
public void setNodes(List<String> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}}
```